# foreach throw BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I have generic class with field `private Dictionary<int, List<T>> items;`

I was shocked to receive an exception in this situation, I use this logic all the time that I'm programming, but today it did not work "properly"

The following example reach `LOG 1` and i get BadImageFormatException, but why ?

```
class MyClass2<T> where T : MyClass1
{
private Dictionary<int, List<T>> items;

public List<T> GetAll()
{
    var result = new List<T>();
    if (items != null )
    {
        //LOG 1
        foreach (int key in this.items.Keys)
        {
            //LOG 2
            var value = this.items[key];
            if (value != null && value.Count > 0)
            {
                result.AddRange(value);
            }
        }
        //LOG 3
    }    
    return result;
}
}
```

I solved that truble with following code `foreach (int key in this.items.Keys.ToList())`, but explain me why that happend

Comment: We need to know what `items` is. If it's an `IEnumerable`, then the `foreach` is probably the first time it's being iterated.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: You should take a look to this MSDN link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7137bfe.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Rather than `foreach (int key in this.items.Keys)
        {
            //LOG 2
            var value = this.items[key];` you should use `foreach (var kvp in this.items)
        { var key = kvp.Key; var value = kvp.Value;
            //LOG 2` This will be faster since it avoids an unnecessary hash lookup. _Unrelated to your current issue though._

Comment: @john is it enough ?

Comment: I'd look at @Adrenaline's link in that case.

Comment: @mjwills i am unable to create "Verifiable" example because in the other places it works, thanks for improvements, it's on

Comment: There isn't much we can suggest then, unfortunately.

Comment: BadImageFormatException can come from a lot more of places (like boxing/unboxing) than your imagination (one example https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/14097).